# How to convert CGFontRef to UIFont?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uifont

I want to use a custom font for a `UILabel`. The custom font is loaded by from a file:

```
NSString *fontPath = ... ; // a TTF file in iPhone Documents folder
CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([fontPath UTF8String]);
CGFontRef customFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
```

How can I convert the `CGFontRef` to a `UIFont` to be used in `[UILabel setFont:]`?

Comment: What iOS version do you need to support? You could load the bundled fonts as `UIFont` instances by editing the Info.plist.

Comment: I'm not sure about converting a CGFontRef into a UIFont but you could create a sub class of UILabel which takes a CGFontRef. Check this [blog](http://blog.mro.name/2010/08/uilabel-with-a-custom-cgfont/) out in doing it

Comment: @Costique iOS 4.3 or later is OK. The font is added by user after downloading the app, so I cannot preset the Info.plist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Conrad's answer is close but doesn't quite work. You need to provide UIFont with the PostScript name, rather than the full name.

```
NSString *fontName = (NSString *)CGFontCopyPostScriptName(fontRef);
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:someSize]
```

Comment: Note that `CGFontCopyPostScriptName` allocates and returns an `CFStringRef` which you have to later `CFRelease`. Casting the return value to NSString is a bad idea for readability.

Answer (score 18):

You can't convert `CGFontRef` to `UIFont` directly but you can register `CGFontRef` using `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` and then create corresponding `UIFont`.

```
NSString* fpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"custom_font_file_name.ttf"];
CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([fpath UTF8String]);
CGFontRef customFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
NSString *fontName = (__bridge NSString *)CGFontCopyFullName(customFont);
CFErrorRef error;
CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(customFont, &error);
CGFontRelease(customFont);
UIFont* uifont = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:12];
```

Comment: I got this error Failed to load font: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coretext error 105 - Could not register the CGFont '<CGFont (0x89919a0): Melville>')

Comment: documentsDirectory.. "Use of undeclared identifier 'documentsDirectory'... did you mean? .... ? ? ?

Answer (score 6):

`CTFontRef` and `UIFont` are [toll-free bridged](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Overview/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH3-SW5), so you can turn your `CGFont` into a `CTFont` and then turn that into a `UIFont`:

```
CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(cgFont, pointSize, NULL, NULL);
UIFont *uiFont = CFBridgingRelease(ctFont);
```

Answer (score 3):

They are, in principle, not directly convertible.  One simple reason is that UIFont encapsulates font size, whereas CGFont is size-independent (with size being a property of the graphics context; see CGContextSetFontSize()).

Assuming that you have otherwise determined what font size you want, you should be able to something like:

```
NSString *fontName = (NSString *)CGFontCopyFullName(someCGFontRef);
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:someSize];
[fontName release];
```

I haven't actually tested this, but it should work (maybe with some minor additions).  I believe that there is a correspondence between names for CGFont and UIFont - but if there isn't, this obviously won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your CGFont to CTFont, but unfortunately neither of those will get you a UIFont. Here are the ways to get a UIFont: ask for a system font, or ask for a font by its PostScript name. Therefore, for custom supplied fonts in a UILabel, I suggest you use the latter.

If you know the font file your app will use ahead of time you can add it to your bundle and load it with **UIFont**, +**fontWithName:size:** as UIFont searches your bundle for a font file with that PostScript name.

For example, the TrueType font file "VeraMono.ttf" has PostScript name "**Bitstream Vera Sans Mono**", so it's loaded into a UILabel like:

`label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitstream Vera Sans Mono" size:12];`

To get PostScript names non-dynamically, use a font tool, or, in the case above the PostScript name happens to be equal to the "Full Name" display by Finder > Get Info.

However, for cases where you won't necessarily know the font's PostScript name ahead of time (such as supporting user-defined fonts), perhaps you can load the filename into NSData and "grep" for its PostScript name...

Good luck,

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Your response, with Josh Brown's answer, helped me 4 years later!

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 4 to get PostScript name (where `font` is the CGFont):

```
let fontName = font?.postScriptName as String?
textLabel.font = UIFont(name: fontName!, size: 17)
```