# In iOS, Is it possible to add a font to the app during runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uifont

In my app I want to let the user download and use fonts, but I don't know how to do this dynamically. I know we have to specify the fonts we want to use in the app's `Info.plist` file, but we can't add anything to that plist file programmatically. There is zynga's library but it is a subclass of `UILabel`.

Please help

Comment: I don't think it is possible to add fonts dynamically.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/inkpad/id400083414?mt=8   please check this app. Inkpad these guyz are providing this facility.

Comment: Well... I mean I think it is not possible to menage UIFonts dynamically without adding them to your app bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider()` followed by `CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont()`. Then you'd have a CTFont, which you can draw using Core Text.

As far as I know there's no way to get a UIFont from a custom font without either having the font in your app bundle and using the Info.plist method (i.e. not downloading it), or using private APIs.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9206121/244340) speculates you might be able to do the conversion to UIFont, but he says he hasn't tried the code.

Comment: Thanks Amy, i am looking at it now.

Comment: You can use it in UIFont, according to Marco Arment: http://www.marco.org/2012/12/21/ios-dynamic-font-loading

Comment: CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont() this method hangs for forever. (iOS 10.2)

Comment: If you've issues with ttf with mutiple styles, check the answer I did in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72287153/1542507

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible:

```
/**
 Downloads a `.ttf` file from an URL and creates an UIFont.
 
 - Parameter url: The URL of the `.ttf` file.
 
 - Precondition: The URL Session must be previously configured at ease.
 */
fileprivate func setFont(url: URL) {
    // Download the font file in .ttf format.
    dataTask = urlSession?.dataTask(with: url,
                                    completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil,
            let data = data,
            (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200,
            // Create a Font Descriptor from the raw data.
            let ctFontDescriptor = CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorFromData(data as CFData) else {
                // Error during the download of the .ttf file.
                self?.error()
                return
        }
        // Create CTFont from the Font Descriptor and convert it to UIFont.
        let font: UIFont = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(ctFontDescriptor, 0.0, nil) as UIFont
        // Do whatever you want with the UIFont :)
        self?.success(font: font)
    })
    dataTask?.resume()
}
```

With this code, you can download a **.ttf** file from the Internet (you could get the file from any other source) containing a font and use it as UIFont.

Comment: The git repo link does not seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to download and register a font during runtime, you need download the font to a local folder and then you can use `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` or `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` to register it.

I found that `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` seems to load TTF with mutiple styles while using `CGDataProvider` with `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` only loads one.

Remember that URL need to be an internal URL, not an http one.

```
    var unmanagedError: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    if CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(url as CFURL, .process, &unmanagedErrorT) == true {
         // SUCCESS CODE
    } else {
         // ERROR CODE
         unmanagedError?.release()
    }
```