# Is it possible to have fonts as an in app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to have different fonts as in app purchases?

I wasn't sure if this was possible due to the fact that the Info.plist must contain the different fonts.

Comment: I was thinking that since you can't change the Info.plist in a shipped app, it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of an in app purchase for my use case, I guess my only option is to put all the in app fonts in the Info.plist before hand.

Comment: Ack.  Comment on a deleted comment.  Well, here is the deleted comment: "You can change the info.plist in a product update, if necessary."

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821211/is-it-possible-to-add-font-to-the-app-during-runtime?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four supported kinds of products that you may sell using In-App Purchase:

1. Content includes digital books, magazines, photos, artwork, game levels, game characters, and other digital content that can be delivered within your application.
2. Functionality products unlock or expand features you’ve already delivered in your application. For example, you could ship a game with multiple smaller games that could be purchased by the user.
3. Services allow your application to charge users for one-time services, such as voice transcription. Each time the service is used is a separate purchase.
4. Subscriptions provide access to content or services on an extended basis. For example, your application might offer monthly access to financial information or to an online game portal.

Fonts fall under category 1.

**See Also**
[Overview of In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1)

Comment: I think you missed the important part of the question. This isn't really about whether custom fonts are allowed to be sold as IAP. The question is how can the app make use of a custom font that has been purchased since normally, custom fonts must be registered in the Info.plist.

Comment: @rmaddy: Well, I still think you can update Info.plist with a product update, so even if you don't have enough clairvoyance to put all of the possible fonts into the list the first time, I don't really see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible.

> I wasn't sure if this was possible due to the Info.plist must contain
>   the different fonts.

So, you just make sure that the fonts you want available to purchase on in your Info.plist correctly.

Comment: According to Marco Arment, you can load them fully dynamically, without needing them in your plist: http://www.marco.org/2012/12/21/ios-dynamic-font-loading