# CGFontCreateWithDataProvider hangs in airplane mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, freeze

When I make a call to `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider` **while in airplane mode**, my apps freeze.  Not in airplane mode, it works fine.  The font is stored on the device, no network access should be happening.

While calling this method to load a local font file:

```
[self registerIconFontWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FontAwesome" withExtension:@"otf"]];
```

The value of `url` in the following method is:
**file:///var/mobile/Applications/48D3DA14-235B-4450-A081-7A6BA6116667/Blah.app/FontAwesome.otf**

```
+ (void)registerIconFontWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSAssert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]], @"Font file doesn't exist");
    CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url);

//******Freezes after the next line******
    CGFontRef newFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
//******FROZEN******

    CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
    CFErrorRef error;
    CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(newFont, &error);
    CGFontRelease(newFont);
}
```

iOS 7.1.x, iPhone 5.

I have no idea why this might happen and haven't been able to find any help out there.  Does anyone have a clue why this might happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: What's the value of `url`?

Comment: @rmaddy you looked too soon, it's there now =)

Comment: why not use `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL()`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the answer after a bit more searching.

According to the following bug report: https://alpha.app.net/jaredsinclair/post/18555292

> If there’s no network connection, CGFontCreateWithDataProvider() hangs
>   in a semaphore trap *if* it’s called during
>   appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Calling it in the next run loop
>   works without hanging.

As noted in the same post, calling

`[UIFont familyNames]`

before `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider()`

resolves the issue.  My code now looks like this and works as expected:

```
+ (void)registerIconFontWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSAssert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]], @"Font file doesn't exist");
    CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url);

    //THE NEXT LINE IS RELEVANT PART
    [UIFont familyNames];

    CGFontRef newFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
    CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
    CFErrorRef error;
    CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(newFont, &error);
    CGFontRelease(newFont);
}
```

Comment: calling `[UIFont familyNames];` fixed my problem! wow! how did you figure this out :o

Comment: @Hlung I googled around and found the bug report mentioned in my answer...saved me =)

Comment: WOW, nice one. how did you discover this?

Comment: @ManuelM. some lucky/frantic googling =)

Comment: This fixed my problem as well, although I was not calling this in airplane mode (i.e. I had a valid network connection). I was attempting to call this from an extension of UIFont, inside an override of the class' `initialize()` method (this is in Swift).

Comment: @DiscDev can you elaborate how [UIFont familyNames]; solved the issue.

Comment: @Sumeet.Jain I do not know.  The original bug report I cited may have had more info, try that link.

Comment: @DiscDev Unfortunately the link to the original bug report no longer works. Do you happen to know if that bug still exists, or what iOS version it was fixed?

Comment: @danyowdee I don't know. I stopped doing iOS development 3 years ago and am exclusively Android now.