# Converting UIFont to CGFont in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uifont

Need to pass `CGFont` for the below function

```
CGFontCreateCopyWithVariations(<#font: CGFont!#>, <#variations: CFDictionary!#>))
```

Comment: What about this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205709/how-to-convert-cgfontref-to-uifont

Comment: Well he is asking for Swift, but I guess this also answers the question: you would need to apply Objective-C here.

Comment: Thanks a ton Grimxn and Peter Branforn

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a small example:

```
var font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)
var fontName = font.fontName as NSString
var cgFont = CGFontCreateWithFontName(fontName);

var copiedFont = CGFontCreateCopyWithVariations(cgFont, nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this with Swift 4 and the accepted answer is no longer quite valid. The following took a `UIFont` and gave me a usable `CGFont`:

```
if let uiFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 36.0),
    let cgFont = CGFont(uiFont.fontName as CFString) {
        // Do stuff        
    }
```

Comment: How do we add the font-size of the UIFont to the CGFont?

Comment: When you are drawing the font with a CGContext you have to call `setFontSize(_ size: CGFloat)` on the CGContext