# Loading and registering CGFonts in a Playground

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, swift-playground

Is there a way to construct a CGFontRef within the context of a Swift Playground? When the following code is run in a playground, 'font' is nil:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FiraSans-Medium", ofType: "otf")
let provider: CGDataProviderRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(path)
let font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider)
let error: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?> = nil
if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, error)) { ...
```

Similar code works fine in the context of a running application, so I suspect some crucial bit of CG init hasn't happened.

Comment: The problem is probably the path

Comment: The otf resource is present under the Playground's resource path

Comment: Why do you need this to work with playground?

Comment: My target font contains symbols related to music notation, and I'm hoping to iterate positioning algorithms quickly, with visual feedback.

Comment: Try putting them at the documents folder

Comment: It looks like this code now works since Xcode 6.3 was released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your font at the Document Directory

```
let directory =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)!
```

It will return your playground documents directory like this one:

```
file:///var/folders/f9/yrxcqv_10m57prx9lwts4qy80000gq/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.Relative-Time-Formating-B3CC63A2-BAE4-4C6B-A482-1A0F14C27D9D/Documents/
```

Delete the first 7 characters, open your finder and select at the Go Menu "Go to Folder" or  press at your keyboard command-shift-G

```
/var/folders/f9/yrxcqv_10m57prx9lwts4qy80000gq/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.Relative-Time-Formating-B3CC63A2-BAE4-4C6B-A482-1A0F14C27D9D/Documents/
```

Paste your playground path there and you will be redirected to the folder where you should place your font.

inside Playground you can find your font using this approach:

```
let documentsUrl = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)!
let documentsPath = documentsUrl.path!
let filePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("FiraSans-Medium.otf")
let foundIt = NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath)    // true
```

Comment: This does it, and registering the font succeeds. It's subsequently available via UIFont.

Comment: @jbouwman how were you able to convert the `CGFont` to `UIFont`? I tried the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205709/how-to-convert-cgfontref-to-uifont) with no luck. The font name it generates fails to initialize a `UIFont`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSBundle.mainBundle()` is where you're going wrong. That's going to give you:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
// /var/folders/fp/j66srs090pvfywgv7xzvflmm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/applications/Foo.app
```

Which is a bundle that does not contain the `otf` files you're looking for. You will need to find the `otf` file using something other than `NSBundle`. Perhaps just hardcode it in:

```
let path = "/Users/jbouwman/projects/foo/FiraSans-Medium.otf"
```

Comment: Hard paths outside of the Resource Path result in errors (sandbox guard?), inside of the Resource Path, in nils, and inside of the DocumentDirectory, success.